# Alloted times for startup shutdown of iphone apps

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How much time is given to the startup and shutdown of an iphone app (and possibly other important routines). I have had programs killed on my iphone by the OS which was overzealous?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The watchdog timer on the iPhone terminates your application if it has been unresponsive for 20 seconds.  Note that Xcode [disables the watchdog timer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2009/qa1592.html) when debugging, so you may need to test on the hardware outside of Xcode to make sure that your application will indeed run.  However, if your application is blocking the main thread for anywhere near 20 seconds, there's something seriously wrong in its design.

Answer (score 2):

The [iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW41) states 5 seconds for shutdown, but I can't find a reference to start-up times.